# How to remove single qotes from sql prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc

I am developing java code where sql query is already, but it it leads to sql injection, I am using setString method to avoid sql injection. But the setstring is adding single quotes for parameter values, so my query is failing. How can I remove single quotes for setString methods.

I have tried to use replaceAll method, but it does not work for preapred statements.

```
String X="where IP ?";

String Y=" group by user";

String Z="order by descend";

query="select appname,user,IP from xyz "+X+" "+Y+Z; --> this is existing query.
```

I am changing query as below

```
query="select appname,user,IP from xyz ? ? ?"; 

Object=connectionObj.prepareStatement(query);

Object.setString(1,X);

Object.setString(2,Y);

Object.setString(3,Z);
```

but here setString method is adding single quoes for the values so my query is failing as syntax error.I tried `replceAll("'"," ")` method but it only works for strings not for prepared statements.I am stuck with syntax error.Please help me out to solve this issue in JAVA.

Comment: This could well just be an example, but don't name a variable `Object`. It's confusing.

Comment: What is `from xyz ? ? ?` supposed to mean?  This is likely not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: You can only parameterize **values**, not query fragments.

Comment: @Tim - It looks like they are trying to supply fragments of SQL command text as parameter values, e.g., `group by user`

Comment: @Gord I think you're right.  There are workarounds for this, but still would be tough to give a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is also SQL injection. Where are the values of X, Y, and Z coming from? Code your program to build up the SQL based on your business needs, adding the fragments of SQL using StringBuilder from within your program. If you have control over the fragments, it is not SQL injection. You should only be using parameters (?) for values compared with the data within your tables. You could also consider a tool like myBatis if you have a need to dynamically create SQL.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did, I hope it will benefit someone:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(); 
String placeholder  = "";
while(rst.next()){
    temp.add(rst.getString("ISSN"));
    placeholder += "?,";
}
placeholder = placeholder.replaceAll(",$", "");
ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from BOOKS where ISSN in "+ "("+placeholder+")");
for (int i=1; i<=temp.size(); i++){
    ps.setString(i, temp.get(i-1));
} 
rs =ps.executeQuery();
```